# Mstest not setting the errorlevel correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, errorlevel

I have a test project that builds fine. I am trying to run the tests using mstest. Here is the command I am executing:

Command:

```
echo mstest.exe /testcontainer:SecurityLogging.Tests\Logging.Tests.dll /resultsfile:%TEST_LOG_ROOT%\Execute_%TestListNode%_1.trx /detail:Owner /detail:Description /nologo /testsettings:Logging.Tests\Local.testsettings /category:"^!E2E&^!Stress&^!Perf"
```

My tests FAILED. If I then check the error level. It is still 0. I did:

```
if %errorlevel%==0 (
   continue;
)
```

and it always continues.

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I started digging and I found this:

http://www.mail-archive.com/ccnet-user@googlegroups.com/msg03027.html

Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you removed the `ECHO` - or is that a transcription error?

Answer (score 0):

`MSTest` is not failing. It executes the tests fine. Your tests are failing and their errors are handled by `MStest`. So, I think you will not get any %errorlevel%.

Comment: How do I find out whether the test run was a clean run or not? I have used this previously and it works. I am wondering if there was any recent update that could have changes this.

Answer (score 0):

I've just confirmed that mstest.exe for Visual Studio 2010 does in fact exit with errorlevel 1 when it runs tests and some of them fail.  When all the tests pass, it returns errorlevel 0.

You can verify this with the following lines in your batch file after running mstest:

```
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

If your batch file is being called by another batch file, and you want to pass the errorlevel back, then you can use `if not %errorlevel% == 0 exit 1` to shortcut your batch file.

Otherwise, as @Magoo indicates, you may have an unnecessary `echo` at the front of your call to mstest.exe.